# MIPS Help. Load Byte error. Address out of range

Tags: mips, mips32

I am trying to add numbers that are in base 5.

Im supposed to prompt the user for 2 separate base 5 number in the form XXXXXX.XXXXX, and then add them.

My current problem is that I am getting an error when I am loading the last digit into a register, so I can start the calculation.

please help! Thanks

```
.data
str: .space 13 # XXXXXX.XXXXX hold 12 chars + 0x00
str2: .space 13
sum: .space 14

printstr: .space 13
printstr2: .space 13
printsum: .space 14

message1: .asciiz "Enter a base 5 number A: "
message2: .asciiz "Enter a base 5 number B: "
message3: .asciiz "Sum of A and B: "
newline: .asciiz "\n"

.text
main:
#get number A
li $v0, 4
la $a0, message1
syscall
li $v0, 8
li $a1, 13
la $a0, str
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, newline
syscall
#get number B
li $v0, 4
la $a0, message2
syscall
li $v0, 8
li $a1, 13
la $a0, str2

syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, newline
syscall

#pointer to input string A
la $s1, str
addi $s1, $s1, 12
#pointer to input string A
la $s2, str2
addi $s2, $s2, 12
#pointer to sum
la $s3, sum
addi $s3, $s3, 13

#other variables
li $t0, 0        # inital carry is 0
li $t1, 1        # counter for looping through string
li $t2, 5        # base 5

loop:
lb $t3, ($s1)    ############################# PROBLEM HERE######
lb $t4, ($s2)    

beq $t3, '.', next
beq $t4, '.', next

subi $t3, $t3, 0x30
subi $t4, $t4, 0x30


add $t5, $t3, $t4

add $t5, $t5, $t0

div $t5, $t2

mflo $t0
mfhi $t5

addi $t5, $t5, 0x30
sb $t5, ($s3)

subi $s1, $s1, 1
subi $s2, $s2, 1
subi $s3, $s3, 1

addi $t1, $t1, 1
ble $t1, 13, loop

addi $t0, $t0, 0x30
sb $t0, ($s3)

next:
subi $s1, $s1, 1 
subi $s2, $s2, 1
#subi $s3, $s3, 1
addi $t1, $t1, 1
j loop

PRINT:   #print the sum

exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up `$s1` to point past `str` and decrement it backwards. Your `loop:` termination is the `ble $t1,13,loop`. When that completes, `$s1` is pointing to the start of the `.data` section (i.e. 0x10010000).

But, then, you "fall through" to `next:` [probably wrong] and decrement `$s1` so it has the value 0x1000ffff. Then, you do `j loop` so the fetch is now coming from an address one byte *below* the start of the `.data` segment (i.e. memory that does not exist)

That's the source of the crash. You probably need a jump inst after the `ble` to continue on to some other code.

But, also, when you do `beq $t3,'.',next` you go to `next:` and decrement *both* pointers. Unless you restrict your input there is no guarantee that *both* `$s1` *and* `$s2` both point to `'.'` at the same time, so you only want to decrement one of them. (e.g. suppose you had `str: 12.3` and `str2: 123.41`)

So, you may need some code to align the two numbers with respect to their decimal points beforehand.